System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: "Попытка десериализации пустого потока."
using BlogCodeFitness.BL.Model;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;

namespace BlogCodeFitness.BL.Controller
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Контроль пользователя.
    /// </summary>
    public class UserController
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Пользователь приложения.
        /// </summary>
        public List<User> Users {get;}
        public User CurrentUser { get;}
        public bool IsNewUser { get;}= false;
        /// <summary>
        /// Создание нового контроллера пользователя.
        /// </summary>
        public UserController(string userName)
        {
            if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(userName))
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("Имя пользователя не может быть пустым",nameof(userName));
            }

            Users = GetUsersData();

            CurrentUser = Users.SingleOrDefault(u => u.Name == userName);
            if (CurrentUser == null)
            {
                CurrentUser = new User(userName);
                Users.Add(CurrentUser);
                IsNewUser = true;
                Save();
            }
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Получить сохраненный список пользователей.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private List<User> GetUsersData()
        {
            var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

            using (var fs = new FileStream("users.dat", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
            {
                if (formatter.Deserialize(fs) is List<User> users)
                {
                    return users;
                }
                else
                {
                    return new List<User>();
                }
            }
        }
        public void SetNewUserData(string genderName, DateTime birthDate , double weight = 1, double height = 1)
        {
            //проверка
            CurrentUser.Gender = new Gender(genderName);
            CurrentUser.BirthDate = birthDate;
            CurrentUser.Weight = weight;
            CurrentUser.Height = height;
            Save();
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Сохранить данные пользователя.
        /// </summary>
        public void Save()
        {
            var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

           using(var fs = new FileStream("users.dat", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
            {
                formatter.Serialize(fs, Users);
            }
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Получить данные пользователя.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>Пользователь приложения.</returns>
        /// <exception cref="FileLoadException"></exception>

    }
}


Ну и???????????

что????????????

Имя, сестра, имя! | Добавьте метку языка программирования. И задайте, собственно, вопрос!

@AlexanderPetrov, да тут вообще непонятно за данные он десериализует.
